# python import module error:serial observed while run the script in jenkins windows shell

Tags: python, jenkins, import

Case 1:

open the command window and execute or python interpreter as below:

py -2.7 Test.py
py -3.4 Test.py

Programming working fine and i am able to get print output Hi.

Case 2:

In Jenkins windows shell

py - 3.4 Test.py --> Programming working fine and i am able to get print output Hi.

case 3:

In Jenkins windows shell

py - 2.7 Test.py -->  error like  import module error:serial

case 4:

Few form they have mentioned need to export the module and try.

I tried as below

Method 1:

export PYHTONPATH =  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\serial:$PYTHONPATH
 py -2.7 Test.py -->  result: import module error:serial

Method 2:

export PYHTONPATH =  C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\serial:$PYTHONPATH
 py -2.7 Test.py --> result: import module error:serial

Method 3:

export PYHTONPATH =  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
 py -2.7 Test.py -->  result: import module error:serial

Method 4:
  "export PYHTONPATH =  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\serial:$PYTHONPATH"
  "export PYHTONPATH =  C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\serial:$PYTHONPATH"

py -2.7 Test.py -->  result: import module error:serial

also other combination.

Can you please help me? How to resolve this issue.

Comment: you should install pyserial again ensuring that you run the install using pip2

Comment: sudo pip2 install pyserial in linux or python -m pip2 install pyserial in windows